# Sidebar into toggleable topbar for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Hello dear Stackoverflow community,

I have problems making a certain page responsive and I need some help.

I'm trying to make my side-navbar responsive and have encountered a few hurdles.

Although I managed to adjust my navbar to the screen size, I don't know how to make my navbar toggle for mobile users so that my navbar doesn't have to take up the whole screen.

My second question is how best to center my navbar in desktop mode like on this page (http://www.christophurwalek.at/) so that my navbar and an image are in the center of the page.

I look forward to your answers!

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- ========== Stylesheet START ========== -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {float: left;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
.sidebar li{
    list-style: none;
}

</style>

<body>

    <!-- ========== NAVBAR START ========== -->
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Logo</a>
    <a href="#">painting</a>
    <a href="#">drawing</a>
    <a href="#">collage</a>
    <a href="#">video</a>
    <a href="#"><li>&nbsp;</li></a>
    <a href="#">current</a>
    <a href="#">text</a>
    <a href="#">biography</a>
    <a href="#">contact</a>

  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <img style="max-width: 700px; height: auto;"src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1000366/pexels-photo-1000366.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First tip try to use vw and vh for instead of px for the size of the things you want to make responsive.

vw = view width

vh = view height

and to change the style when the window size change try to use:

```
@media screen and (min-width : the size of the screen where your style has to change) {
    your style
}
```

min-width is for when the window is over a certain width

max-width is for when the window is under a certain width

min-height is for when the window is over a certain height

max-height is for when the window is under a certain height

Answer (score 0):

@asar13,

please follow the links below and you will find some very useful information related to your questions.

> how to make my navbar toggle for mobile users

https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/modern-responsive-navbar-with-css-grid-and-media-query

https://medium.com/csun-metalab/creating-a-simple-mobile-first-grid-system-1e883a85fa3f

> how best to center my navbar in desktop mode

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

In a way, a response for both of your questions is css `display: grid;`

Take care and happy learning,
Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be linking to bootstrap but not using it. Try using the .container .row and .col classes to center your content. Also consider upgrading to Bootstrap 4 or 5.

For the Nav head to Bootstraps built in nav component https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

or Bootstrap 4 nav: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidebar {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        /*width: 400px;*/
        background-color: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .sidebar a {
        display: block;
        color: #666666;
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar a.active {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #4d4d4d;
    }

    .sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    }

    div.content {
        margin-left: 400px;
        padding: 1px 16px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .sidebar {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        .sidebar a {float: left;}
        div.content {margin-left: 0;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
        .sidebar a {
            text-align: center;
            float: none;
        }
    }
    .sidebar li{
        list-style: none;
    }

</style>

<body>

<!-- ========== NAVBAR START ========== -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col sidebar">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Logo</a>
            <a href="#">painting</a>
            <a href="#">drawing</a>
            <a href="#">collage</a>
            <a href="#">video</a>
            <a href="#"><li>&nbsp;</li></a>
            <a href="#">current</a>
            <a href="#">text</a>
            <a href="#">biography</a>
            <a href="#">contact</a>

        </div>

        <div class="col content">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <img style="max-width: 700px; height: auto;"src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1000366/pexels-photo-1000366.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```